# Excel 2013 chart - setting time intervals in vertical axis

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013, charts, time

I have time (mm:ss) in the vertical axis of a bar chart. 
I want to set the following parameters:

- min - 0
- max - 12:00
- major ticks: every 2:00 min (0, 2:00, 4:00, etc.)
- minor ticks: every 0.5 min (0:30, 1:30, 2:30, etc.)

I can't figure out how to do this, and what is the rationale for it. I read that Excel uses a day for these parameters, but I just don't know how to apply it to my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just divide all your time values by 24 hours
(which is 1440 minutes). 
So, for example, your max value should be entered as 0.008333 (12÷1440).

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it doesn't seem right. With a value of 0.52 for the max, I get 12:15, which is about right, but I would like it to be 12:00.

Comment: @user3315563: Huh?  Are you talking about 12 hours or 12 minutes?  I interpreted it as 12 minutes, since you said times were mm:ss.  If you want 12 hours, where did you get the value of 0.52?  12:00 ÷ 24:00 = 0.5000000000.

Comment: That's correct, I want 12 minutes. So maybe my time format is incorrect?

Comment: Well, I don't know what your situation is.  Did you try 0.008333?  What results are you getting?

Comment: Too bad a can't attach a pic. Anyway, the axis show 0:00 and nothing else.

Comment: I had a mistake with the time format in my table. I fixed it and now it as wanted!